# Convert pandas dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas

I have a [`pandas.Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) with the following columns:

```
a_1  ab_1  ac_1    a_2   ab_2   ac_2
2      3     4      5     6      7
```

How do I convert it into the following?

```
a    ab    ac 
2     3     4
5     6     7
```

I was trying to use pandas melt to convert from wide to long format, but not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  ab  ac
0  2   3   4
1  5   6   7
```

---

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   a  ab  ac
1  2   3   4
2  5   6   7
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but for some reason, it doesn't work. Some issue with column names. Can you please help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807104/wide-to-long-returns-empty-output-python-dataframe/56808192?noredirect=1#comment100170775_56808192

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the columns by a multi-index and stack:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple))
df = df.stack()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that:

#### Code:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [c.split('_') for c in df.columns], names=['col', 'row'])

df.melt().pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value')
```

#### How?

1. Create a [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) for the columns by splitting on `_`.
2. [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the data frame and then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on the elements from the original column names.

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[range(2, 8)],
    columns='a_1 ab_1 ac_1 a_2 ab_2 ac_2'.split()
)
print(df)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [c.split('_') for c in df.columns], names=['col', 'row'])

print(df.melt().pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value'))
```

#### Results:

```
   a_1  ab_1  ac_1  a_2  ab_2  ac_2
0    2     3     4    5     6     7

col  a  ab  ac
row           
1    2   3   4
2    5   6   7
```

#### pandas < 0.20.0

If using pandas prior to 0.20.0, `melt()` like:

```
print(pd.melt(df).pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='value'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the dataframe into two, then rename the columns, and finally concatenate them:

```
cols = ['a', 'ab', 'ac']
df1 = df[["a_1", "ab_1", "ac_1"]]
df2 = df[["a_2", "ab_2", "ac_2"]]
df1.columns = cols
df2.columns = cols
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `pnd.melt` you should probably use the `value_vars` and `value_name` parameters:

```
df_a = pnd.melt(df, value_vars=['a_1', 'a_2'], value_name='a')[['a']]
df_ab = pnd.melt(df, value_vars=['ab_1', 'ab_2'], value_name='ab')[['ab']]
df_ac = pnd.melt(df, value_vars=['ac_1', 'ac_2'], value_name='ac')[['ac']]
df_final = df_a.join(df_b).join(df_c)
```

Alternatively, taking a more functional approach:

```
col_prefixes = ['a', 'ab', 'ac']
df_cuts = map(lambda x: pnd.melt(df, value_vars=['%s_1' % x, '%s_2' % x], value_name=x)[[x]], col_prefixes)
df_final = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y), df_cuts)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is builtin function [wide_to_long](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for more see in documentation:

```
In [115]: df
Out[115]: 
   a_1  ab_1  ac_1  a_2  ab_2  ac_2
0    2     3     4    5     6     7

In [116]: df['id'] = df.index

In [117]: df
Out[117]: 
   a_1  ab_1  ac_1  a_2  ab_2  ac_2  id
0    2     3     4    5     6     7   0
In [118]: pd.wide_to_long(df, ['a','ab','ac'],i='id',j='num',sep='_')
Out[118]: 
        a  ab  ac
id num           
0  1    2   3   4
   2    5   6   7
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please helo me with this post? I get an empty output when I changed the column names. Not sure whther the issue is with column names or anything else. Help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807104/wide-to-long-returns-empty-output-python-dataframe/56808192?noredirect=1#comment100170775_56808192.