# Convert pandas dataframe from wide to long when some columns have multiple separators

Tags: python, pandas

From [Convert pandas dataframe from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123924/convert-pandas-dataframe-from-wide-to-long/45124130#45124130). how can I extend the solutions to work on a database of the form:

```
a_1  ab_col_1  ac_1    a_2   ab_col_2   ac_2
2      3        4      5     6          7
```

The issue here is the repeating separator in some columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with parameter `n=1` for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1)
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  ab_col  ac
0  2       3   4
1  5       6   7
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', expand=True, n=1)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   a  ab_col  ac
1  2       3   4
2  5       6   7
```