# Convert dataframe from wide to long - pandas

Tags: pandas, split, reshape

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index    S_1 S_2 S_3 S_4
 0        1    0   0   1
 1        1    1  Nan Nan
```

I am trying to change it from long to wide. Eg.

```
index num S
 0     1  1
 0     2  0
 0     3  0
 0     4  1
 1     1  1
 1     2  1
 1     3  Nan
 1     4  Nan
```

I have tried the following code, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123924/convert-pandas-dataframe-from-wide-to-long) answer, but I get the following error:

```
matches_df.columns = matches_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Why am I unable to split on the "_"? There is other information in the columns which I would like to preserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `pandas.wide_to_long`, which is nice when the columns have stubs like that.

```
import pandas as pd

df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
df['id'] = df.index
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='S_', i='id', j='num').reset_index().rename(columns={'S_':'S'})

#  id num  index    S
#0   0   1      0  1.0
#1   1   1      1  1.0
#2   0   2      0  0.0
#3   1   2      1  1.0
#4   0   3      0  0.0
#5   1   3      1  NaN
#6   0   4      0  1.0
#7   1   4      1  NaN
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. I get the following error:  Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented. What does that mean?

Comment: Fixed it. I just needed to reset the index.

Comment: @oli5679 great! yeah, looked like the index wasn't originally unique.