# Pandas wide_to_long with list of stubs

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following dataframe:

```
        1_1       1_2       1_3       1_4       1_5       2_1  ...       9_5      10_1      10_2      10_3      10_4      10_5

0  0.049400  0.063812  0.097736 -0.077222  0.112779 -0.201620  ...  0.138246  0.015369 -0.083559 -0.186949  0.158505 -0.046787 
1 -0.169837  0.093606  0.043157  0.095289 -0.078525 -0.026500  ... -0.054344  0.008955  0.045036  0.198438  0.197416 -0.057831 
2 -0.192915  0.001477  0.077699  …
```

I want to obtain something like this:

```
cat     u       i       mouse       

0       1       1      0.049400 
1       1       1     -0.169837
2       1       1     -0.192915
0       1       2      0.063812
1       1       2      0.093606
2       1       2      0.001477
…
```

Essentially, the lines represent the value of the cat column, the number before the underscore represents the u column and the number after represents the i column. Lastly, the mouse column is the value for the combination of the previous factors.

However, the solution should work for any data in such format.

So far, I have this, considering I have access to the list of u (in this case 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and i (1,2,3,4,5), but the solution should work for different lists and different numbers of lines as well.

```
u_seq_stub = [u + '_' for u in u_seq] 
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, u_seq_stub, i='u', j='i').reset_index().rename(columns={'_':'u'})
```

This doesn't work however, and throws "KeyError: "None of [Index(['userid'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]""... I've also consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087135/convert-dataframe-from-wide-to-long-pandas/50087347#50087347) and it doesn't seem that different from what I want but there must be something I am misunderstanding.

I appreciate in advance any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split` by all columns for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), change levels for new columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last convert it to columns by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.unstack().rename_axis(('u','i','cat')).reset_index(name='mouse')
print (df.head(10))
   u  i  cat     mouse
0  1  1    0  0.049400
1  1  1    1 -0.169837
2  1  1    2 -0.192915
3  1  2    0  0.063812
4  1  2    1  0.093606
5  1  2    2  0.001477
6  1  3    0  0.097736
7  1  3    1  0.043157
8  1  3    2  0.077699
9  1  4    0 -0.077222
```

Your solution should be changed first with parameter `sep` in [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), then another reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with some data cleaning:

```
u_seq_stub = ['1','2',...,'9','10']
#alternative
#u_seq_stub = [str(x) for x in range(1,11)]


df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                     u_seq_stub, 
                     i='index', 
                     j='i', 
                     sep='_')
      .stack()
      .reset_index(name='mouse')
      .rename(columns={'index':'cat', 'level_2':'u'})
      .astype({'i':int, 'u':int})
      .sort_values(['u','i','cat'])
      )
print (df.head(10))
    cat  i  u     mouse
0     0  1  1  0.049400
12    1  1  1 -0.169837
24    2  1  1 -0.192915
3     0  2  1  0.063812
15    1  2  1  0.093606
25    2  2  1  0.001477
5     0  3  1  0.097736
17    1  3  1  0.043157
26    2  3  1  0.077699
7     0  4  1 -0.077222
```

Comment: wide_to_long is the right way for this question :-)  BTW happy holiday

Comment: Thanksgiving here :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen wau, so happy holiday too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`. To create `cat` column you could use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
new_df=df.melt(var_name='u_i',value_name='mouse')
new_df['cat']=new_df.groupby('u_i').cumcount()
new_df[['u','i']]=new_df['u_i'].str.split('_',expand=True)
new_df=new_df.drop('u_i',axis=1).reindex(columns=['cat','u','i','mouse'])

print(new_df)

   cat  u  i     mouse
0    0  1  1  0.049400
1    1  1  1 -0.169837
2    2  1  1 -0.192915
3    0  1  2  0.063812
4    1  1  2  0.093606
5    2  1  2  0.001477
6    0  1  3  0.097736
7    1  1  3  0.043157
8    2  1  3  0.077699
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a way to still include the value of the cat column though? Meaning in the final result there would be 4 columns total? Other than that this is the perfect solution

Comment: yes, you could use `groupby.cumcount` . I have updated my solution!

Comment: it is index names I think

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

result = (df
         .add_suffix('_mouse')
         .pivot_longer(
             names_to = ('u', 'i', '.value'), 
             names_sep = '_', 
             names_transform = int,
             ignore_index = False)
         .rename_axis(index = 'cat')
         )

result.head(10)

     u  i     mouse
cat
0    1  1  0.049400
1    1  1 -0.169837
2    1  1 -0.192915
0    1  2  0.063812
1    1  2  0.093606
2    1  2  0.001477
0    1  3  0.097736
1    1  3  0.043157
2    1  3  0.077699
0    1  4 -0.077222
```

The `.value` placeholder determines which parts of the column names stays as headers, while the rest are cumulated into `u` and `I` columns; the `names_transform` parameter offers an efficient way to apply astype (which is what is used under the hood) to the `u` and `I` columns.