# pandas: melt multiple columns with the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe:

```
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
|   |  A  |  B  | C_10 | C_20 | D_10 | D_20 |
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |
+---+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Now I'd like to melt the columns `C_10`, `C_20`, `D_10`, `D_20` to obtain a Dataframe as follows:

```
+---+-----+-----+----+---+---+
|   |  A  |  B  | N  | C | D |
+---+-----+-----+----+---+---+
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 10 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 20 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 10 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 20 | 6 | 8 |
+---+-----+-----+----+---+---+
```

Is there a easy way to do this? Thanks!

**EDIT**: I tried `wide_to_long`, but this doesn't work if there are duplicated rows in the Dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'combination': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'A': [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
    'B': [0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4],
    'C_10': [1, 5, 6, 7],
    'C_20': [2, 6, 7, 8],
    'D_10': [3, 7, 8, 9],
    'D_20': [4, 8, 9, 10],
})
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|    combination    A    B  C_10  C_20  D_10  D_20 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 0            1  0.1  0.3     1     2     3     4 |
| 1            1  0.1  0.3     5     6     7     8 |
| 2            2  0.2  0.4     6     7     8     9 |
| 3            2  0.2  0.4     7     8     9    10 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

If I use `wide_to_long` I get the following error:

```py
> pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['C','D'], i=['combination', 'A', 'B'], j='N', sep='_').reset_index()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-cc5863fa7ecc> in <module>
----> 1 pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['C','D'], i=['combination', 'A', 'B'], j='N', sep='_').reset_index()

pandas/core/reshape/melt.py in wide_to_long(df, stubnames, i, j, sep, suffix)
    456 
    457     if df[i].duplicated().any():
--> 458         raise ValueError("the id variables need to uniquely identify each row")
    459 
    460     value_vars = [get_var_names(df, stub, sep, suffix) for stub in stubnames]

ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row
```

The parameter `i` is described as "Column(s) to use as id variable(s).", but I don't understand what this exactly means.

Comment: does this work for u : [wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087347/7175713)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['C','D'], i=['A','B'], j='N', sep='_').reset_index()
print (df)
     A    B   N  C  D
0  0.1  0.2  10  1  3
1  0.1  0.2  20  2  4
2  0.3  0.4  10  5  7
3  0.3  0.4  20  6  8
```

EDIT: If possible combinations of `A, B` columns are not unique is possible create helper column with convert index to column `index`, apply solution and last remove level `index`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['C','D'],
                      i=['index','A','B'], 
                      j='N', 
                      sep='_')
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)

     A    B   N  combination  C   D
0  0.1  0.3  10            1  1   3
1  0.1  0.3  20            1  2   4
2  0.1  0.3  10            1  5   7
3  0.1  0.3  20            1  6   8
4  0.2  0.4  10            2  6   8
5  0.2  0.4  20            2  7   9
6  0.2  0.4  10            2  7   9
7  0.2  0.4  20            2  8  10
```

Comment: I ran into another issue and edited my original post.

Comment: @joe-92 - Edited answer.